# Mobile Vision API BarcodeDetector only detects in centre of the screen

Tags: android, barcode, android-vision, vision-api

I'm using the BarcodeDetector from the Mobile Vision API on the Google Play Services (Version 10.2.0) for my app. I pretty much took the code from the smaple app they provide:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

And the barcodes are only detected if they are in the middle/centre of the screen. Is there any way of increasing this to extend the whole screen/camera preview? Its a bit misleading for the user unless you add a rectangle in the centre leading them to place the barcode inside.

Any help on how to accomplish this is welcome!

Comment: for me they are not detected at all... wonder why

Comment: SAME HERE .. WORKS FINE ON KITKAT AND NOT ON ANDROID 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this only happens to DataMatrix due to the lack of finder patterns. For the rest of Barcodes it works everywhere on the screen.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/194